# $this->renderTotals() which renders block?

Tags: magento

Hello (sorry for my english)

The file  `/app/design/frontend/my-theme/default/template/checkout/cart/totals.phtml` has the command:

```
    <tbody>
        <?php echo $this->renderTotals(); ?>
    </tbody>
```

In my theme, not charge the purchase price in the shopping cart at: ... mystore.com / checkout / cart /

`$this->renderTotals()` renders which block?

Comment: Start with `<?php echo get_class($this) ?>`

Comment: you can use path hints to get idea of Block class.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I just spent an hour searching for this myself.  The .phtml files that get called by this function are inside tax/checkout.

For instance, to change the "Grand Total" edit the file:

```
/app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/tax/checkout/grandtotal.phtml
```

Comment: Hi, I found the problem, the module was disabled. Mage_Tax in http://my-store.com/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/advanced/